# SlitherLITS: Don't colour outside the lines

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, slitherlink

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #13: Variety Slitherlinks](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/monthly-topic-challenge-13-variety-slitherlinks).</sub>

---

Adding a bit of colour to enhance the loopy goodness of a traditional Slitherlink.

- Draw a single, non-intersecting loop that only consists of horizontal and vertical segments between the dots.
- Numbers inside a cell indicate how many of the edges of that cell are part of the loop.
- Shade the interior of the loop so that every cell is part of an L, I, T, or S tetromino.
- No 2×2 group of cells can be entirely shaded.
- When two tetrominoes share an edge, they must not be of the same type (L, I, T, or S), regardless of rotations or reflections.
  [image]

Should be solvable by hand with no guessing/backtracking.

[Penpa link](https://tinyurl.com/slitherLITS-1)
(If you want the Penpa automated checker to work, Use Green for the loop, and (DG, GR, LG, BK) for shading.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What a wonderful puzzle!

> I started with typical sli-li deductions but had to use all the rules to disambiguate.

e.g.,:

> [image: Hint1] The adjacency restriction helps disambiguate L and S.

Solution:

> [image: Solution]

How I started out:

> [image: Starting out] Got this far with standard slitherlink (I think?)

> These squares must be part of an L with long tail up or down due to T adjacency. The `x` in the upper left is needed to avoid a region with area 1 or 3. [image: tetromino deduction]

Comment: Nicely done. Can you add some more detail on your solve path. I'm curious to see how close it was to the intended route, or if there are shortcuts I missed when testing/tweaking.

Comment: @fljx Is it fine if I add an answer with more detail and explanation?

Comment: Sure.  I'll try and retrace my steps and update later.

Comment: @fljx, I'm sorry. I deleted most of my solving path while trying to highlight one step in Penpa...still getting the hang of it. I added some of my initial steps, at least.

Comment: @newQOpenWid I'd be interested to see it, but I will be accepting n1000's answer as it is complete and was the first one posted.

Comment: @n1000 When using Penpa, I make heavy use of the "clone" button. It does what it says, and gives you a clone of your current position in a new tab, complete with undo/redo history. I find it very useful for creating an instant backup if I'm about to make a potentially destructive change.

Comment: Your "started out" image is incorrect - the 3 at (1, 5) is not going to work.

Comment: It's a good puzzle.  I think the disambiguation n1000 mentions at the start is the only place I had to use the "no adjacency" rule.  I used the "no 2x2 inside the loop" rule quite a bit.

Comment: @Spitemaster good catch. I corrected that later but lost the penpa history while retracing my steps.